# How to find text in another column Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in column1 and column2, If column1 text matched anywhere in another column2 then result should be like c column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TEXTSPLIT()` and `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()` may work. Try-

```
=BYROW(B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(x,," "),COUNTIFS(A2:A3,TEXTSPLIT(x,," ")),""))))
```

I have used `TEXTJOIN()`, if there any possibility to have multiple keywords.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula in `C2`:

`=MAP(B2:B5,LAMBDA(ζ,IFNA(LOOKUP(1,0/SEARCH(A2:A3,ζ),A2:A3),"")))`

Answer (score 0):

[image: ans]

the another ans here which supports on all versions of excel but its not an array formula..
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^10,SEARCH($A$2:$A$3,B2),$B$2:$B$5),"")